# how does java deserialize an object whose class isn't on the classpath but whose superclass is?

Tags: java, serialization, polymorphism

Say I have class Foo that extends Bar.  I create an instance of Foo and serialize it to a file.

Some other code reads that file and attempts to recreate the instances it contains.  Class Bar is visible to this code but not class Foo.

How is it able to deserialize back into an instance of Bar?  Is class hierarchy metadata included in the serialized output?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself to see if it works at all?

Comment: It seems to be working, but the code I'm dealing with is somewhat more complicated than just writing a single class to a file.  I'll fool around tomorrow and see if I can't boil it down to a tiny example.

Answer (score 4):

It simply can't deserialize it. The class must be present in the class path.

Answer (score 0):

the only way it could work is if the code that serialized the instance, first serialized the class bytes, and on the reader side, the class bytes were read, and a class loader was used to create the deserialized class before reading the instance.